# Python how to create a dictionary using the values in multiple pandas dataframe columns as tuple keys and a single column as value

Tags: python, dataframe, data-science

I would like to create a dictionary using the values in the pandas' data frame multiple columns as tuple keys and single-column values as the value(s). And where there are no values for a particular tuple pair, I would like to assign a generic value of say 99999. This latter part is proving to be a challenge and I wish to seek help from this forum on how to achieve this task. Thank you.

Sample extract data:

|  | Periods(Days) | Factory | Warehouse | Sales Outlets | Products | Dist Fact-Whse |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | Berlin | Teltow | Magdeburg | Maracuja | 19.6 |
| 1 | 2 | Hamburg | Wismar | Lubeck | Himbeer | 126.2 |
| 2 | 3 | Berlin | Kleinmachnow | Halle | Malaga | 26.9 |
| 3 | 4 | Hamburg | Wismar | Lubeck | Waldmeister | 126.2 |
| 4 | 5 | Berlin | Kleinmachnow | Leipzig | Walnuss | 26.9 |

Based on the above data set, the following piece of code is how I am creating my dictionary object(s) from the data frame:

```
F = df.Factory.drop_duplicates().to_list()
W = df.Warehouse.drop_duplicates().to_list()

dist1 = {};

for i in df.index:
    key = (df.at[i, 'Factory'], df.at[i, 'Warehouse'])
    value = df.at[i, 'Dist Fact-Whse']
    dicT = {key : value}
    dist1.update(dicT)

for f in F:
    for w in W:
        if (f, w) not in dist1:
            dist1[(f, w)] = 9999
```

I get my desired or expected outcome: `{('Berlin', 'Teltow'): 19.6, ('Hamburg', 'Wismar'): 126.2, ('Berlin', 'Kleinmachnow'): 26.9, ('Berlin', 'Wismar'): 9999, ('Hamburg', 'Teltow'): 9999, ('Hamburg', 'Kleinmachnow'): 9999},`

but this is too elaborous, time consuming, and not efficient as I have a of other parameter similar to "dist1" to create in my entire code.

I kindly welcome a more elegant and smart solution to this issue.

Comment: 1 - Instead of using the .at[] function, you can directly access the values in the dataframe by using the df.loc[] function. This is more efficient, and also makes the code more readable:  .....   key = (df.loc[i, 'Factory'], df.loc[i, 'Warehouse'])    value = df.loc[i, 'Dist Fact-Whse']    dist1[key] = value  ......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a *proposition* with [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) from [itertools](/questions/tagged/itertools).

```
d = df.groupby(["Factory","Warehouse"])["Dist Fact-Whse"].first().to_dict()
combs = list(product(df["Factory"].unique(), df["Warehouse"].unique()))
dist1 = {k:v for v,k in zip([d.get(c, 99999) for c in combs], combs)}
```

This looks shorter (and maybe fancier) but not sure if it's faster. I'll let you give it a try yourself !

Output :

```
print(dist1)

{('Berlin', 'Teltow'): 19.6,
 ('Berlin', 'Wismar'): 99999,
 ('Berlin', 'Kleinmachnow'): 26.9,
 ('Hamburg', 'Teltow'): 99999,
 ('Hamburg', 'Wismar'): 126.2,
 ('Hamburg', 'Kleinmachnow'): 99999}
```